# A true divisibility lemma like this false one: $\,a \mid x,\ b\mid y\,\Rightarrow\, a + b \mid x + y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I remember reading about a divisibility lemma which says something like if $a \mid x$ and $b \mid y$ then $a + b \mid x + y$. Obviously this one isn't true, but what is the actual lemma I am thinking of?

Comment: It is true that $\ a\mid x,\ b\mid y\,\Rightarrow\, ab\mid xy.\ $ Maybe that's what you are thinking of.

Answer (score 7):

Not true. $2\mid 2$, $3\mid 6$, but $2+3=5\not\mid 8=2+6$. You probably mean $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$ implies $a\mid b+c$. That is true.

Comment: No, it's not that one. Is there another one?

Comment: $a\mid b,c\implies a\mid bx+cy$ for any $x,y$ integers?  @Kaish

Comment: Hmm, no, not that one either :(